# Scraping a html text document

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I need to web scrape a particular website but it does not allow web scraping(403 error). I'm thinking about copying the website's html data that I need and putting it into a txt document where I can scrape it as if it was a webpage. Is this possible to do or is there a better way of going about this?

Comment: are you sure that you are allowed to visit that website?, try checking it from a browser

Comment: For future reference, you should include information about what you've searched for and/or what you've tried already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have linux/unix, you can use wget/curl to download the webpage. This copies the html source code into a file in your root directory. For example, you can use

```
wget https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51412042/scraping-a-html-text-document
```

to get the source code for this webpage.

To process this and get rid of some of the tags, you can copy the following into a new file by using vim/nano and run it (after performing chmod +x filename) by using `./script.sh filename`. You can also add other sed commands to get rid of other tags.

```
cat $1 |
sed "s/<html>//g" |
sed "s/</html>//g" |
sed "s/<head>//g" |
sed "s/</head>//g" |
```